# How can I pass a dictionary through "get_success_message" function in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to pass a dictionary through the "get_success_message" function but I just can't.
I need more than a String on my message (title, color...)
What am I doing wrong?

My view:

```
class PeliculasEdit(SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Pelicula
    form_class = PeliculaForm
    template_name = "videoclub/peliculas_edit.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('peliculas_manage')
    message_data = {
        'color':'success',
        'titulo':'Película editada',
        'mensaje':'La película se ha editado correctamente',
    }

    def get_success_message(self, cleaned_data):
        return self.message_data
```

My template where i'm using the message:

```
{% if messages %}

    {% for message in messages %}
    <div class="toast show" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
        <div class="toast-header">
        </div>
        <div class="toast-body">
            <p>{{message.color}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}

{% endif %}
```

I thought i had to {{message.color}} for example. But that's wrong.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot pass a dictionary in this way using the `SuccessMessageMixin` and the `get_success_message` method.

The [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/messages/#adding-messages-in-class-based-views) say this about the `get_success_message` function:

> The cleaned data from the form is available for string interpolation
>   using the %(field_name)s syntax. For ModelForms, if you need access to
>   fields from the saved object override the get_success_message()
>   method.

The returned value of the `get_success_message` function is the `message` attribute which is a string sent to the messages framework. The `SuccessMessageMixin` is a shortcut for creating a success message, such as this:

```
messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Profile details updated.')
```

It sounds like what you are looking for is how to add [extra tags to a message](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/messages/#adding-extra-message-tags):

```
messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'My success message string', extra_tags='color_success')
```

This is a duplicate of [How can I add additional data to Django messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43588876/how-can-i-add-additional-data-to-django-messages)